# style specific parts of an h3 element

Tags: html, css

my current html:

```
<section class="menu-group">
                    <h2 class="menu-group-name">Appetizers</h2>
                        <div class="menu-item-line">
                            <h3 class="menu-item">Battered Cauliflower(GF,SF), Tofu (GF), or Kalebone (SF)</h3>
                            <h3 class="menu-item-price">$3.90/ea</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-item-line">
                            <h3 class="menu-item">Herb Potatoes (GF)</h3>
                            <h3 class="menu-item-price">$3.50</h3>
                        </div>
                        <p class="item-desc">A tasty order of our baked seasoned potatoes</p>

                        <div class="menu-item-line">
                            <h3 class="menu-item">Eggless Bowl (GF)</h3>
                            <h3 class="menu-item-price">$3.00</h3>
                        </div>
                            <p class="item-desc">Our most popular eggless salad served chilled with whole wheat crackers</p>    
                </section>
```

and the relevant css:

```
.menu-item, .menu-item-price {
    font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: .5em 0;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;      
}

.menu-item {
    max-width: 300px;
}

.menu-item-price  {
    float: right;
    /*margin: 0 0 0 5px;*/
}

.item-desc {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;       
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    /*float: left;*/
    max-width: 300px;
    /*font-style: italic;*/
    margin: 0;
}
```

Is there a way to grab all "(GF,SF)" (and all other permutations of "___free") using css and make the text slightly smaller?  I could not find a way except altering the markup.  Thanks

Comment: With just CSS, you would need to wrap the text with another HTML element like a span: `<h3>Battered Cauliflower<span>(GF,SF)</span></h3>` and then style that element along the lines of: `h3 > span { font-size: 0.8em; }`

Comment: Can you explain why you can't alter your markup? It seems that semantically you would want to call this out with or without CSS.

Comment: Hynes, you might be right.  I'm new to the "best practices" in markup.  I will add the markup since that seems to be the consensus.   Thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do without altering markup, but you will have to use javascript or jquery for that.. but if you are only sticking to css to accomplish it, you will have to alter the markup.. need to catch it in `<span>` and use `h3 > span` and give the new font size

Comment: `<small>` might be a better term semantically since the OP is looking to reduce the font-size.

Answer (score 1):

You might try wrapping each abbreviation in a `abbr` tag and then use the title attribute to provide a key to the meaning of the abbreviation.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/abbr.html#abbr

You can then define a CSS rule for `abbr` to style it as you want.

As for the opening and closing parentheses, maybe use first-child and last child selectors with pseudo elements.

```html
<abbr title="Good Food">GF</abbr>
```

Comment: would i include the title attr every time?  is that proper etiquette?  or just the first time?

Comment: As far as best practice, I would include the title attribute in each tag.  This is more of a user interface design/usability issue and there may be a range of opinions about how best to proceed.